# Relational Algebra Check if all items belong to the collection

Tags: relational-algebra

I am a newbie in relational algebra, and I got stuck on this question for a few days now. Help plz.

[image]

Comment: What constitutes an owner owning a whole collection? Is it having three same collections or having any three collections?

Comment: if all the items for the collection have the same owner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

We will perform a grouping and aggregate function together. First, we group according to `Collection` and then we just do a count distinct aggregate operation on the `Owner`. Let us call our resulting relation `temp`.

Using this resulting relation, we just find the tuples that have a count distinct value of equal to one which would indicate that one person owns the whole set.

Once we find the tuples, we can simply do a natural join with the original relation to find the owners name.

Hope this helps.